# Bokeh Standalone chart not working in docker

Tags: docker, bokeh, bokehjs

i have a simple program that displays a bokeh plot in new html file from output_file() from python3.7. i also have a chart.html in templates folder with the following entries and everything works fine on local machine but the issue i am facing is when i dockerize the application where i get an error when i run the program to show bokeh chart from container.

```
if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                  embed_document(root);
                } else {
                  var attempts = 0;
                  var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                    if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                      clearInterval(timer);
                      embed_document(root);
                    } else {
                      attempts++;
                      if (attempts > 100) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
                      }
                    }
                  }, 10, root)
                }
              })(window);
            });
          };
          if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
```

my template/chart.html has

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bokeh Chart!</title>
    <link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.5.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.5.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.5.min.css" type="text/css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>bokeh chart</h1>
    {{ div|safe }}
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.2.3.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.2.3.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.2.3.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.5.min.js"></script>

    {{ script|safe }}
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried changing this to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

<link
    href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.2.3.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>line chart with bokeh in flask</h1>
        {{ div|safe }}
        <div class="bk-root" id="f3e00085-05ba-43da-b01b-b67bf8cc2246" data-root-id="1612"></div>
        <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.2.3.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {{ script|safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```

still i am getting the same error "Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing". i tried reading every possible stack entry but most of the topics are on bokeh server. if anyone faced similar issue or know what the problem is pls let me know.

thanks,
meekey

Comment: Does the docker have network access? Not being able to access `cdn.bokeh.org` remotely would be one explanation. Also note that the version in your template needs to match whatever package version you used to generate the script with.

Comment: i tried changing the version still did not work. i am using bokeh 2.2.3. i can see that bokeh is returning the json data but its not launching a new window to show the chart. i check the logs and i see the exact same Bokehjs missing under condition when running the app locally which launches new html to show the chart. but from docker its not launching a new window

Comment: This seems like docker issue. Is it even possible to just run a browser from inside a docker container without extra work? https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8

Comment: i think you are right. but i thought bokeh output_file() in conjunction with show() will post the chart using the template anywhere and everywhere you run the code. there is not much documentation i can find for bokeh standalone and docker. most posts are on bokeh server

Comment: `output_file` + `show` is just a thin wrapper that saves the HTML file to the filesystem and then and calls the Python standard library `webbrowser.open` function on it. It can't do anything that can't do.